# Как проверить, существует ли в базе таблица?

Tags: sqlite, java

Как проверить, существует ли в базе таблица? И как обновить бд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в блоке try{} catch выполнить запрос select from из этой таблицы. Если таблица есть, то запрос пройдёт и блок catch не выполниться - значит таблица существует; если таблицы нет, будет исключение и блок catch выполниться - значит таблицы нет.